# How to store 3d models aspecially STL files in database?

Tags: database, stl, 3d-modelling

I'am reading an STL file in my WPF c# application. I want to store it to database. All database connections are done but I don't know how to store 3d model in database. What kind of converting needed for this purpose? And later similarly I want to get that information from database to turn it 3d models.Is there any basic function for STL converting to binaries then merging it again?
I'am using Helix Toolkit for 3d model reading and visualizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update#1: I store STL files in database. Firstly I convert STL file to binary, then read all bytes. To store database I partitioning it to 400KB for each part. Then I load all of part to database sequentially. Therefore it is much faster to load part by part contrary loading all files in one step.

For any answer which present improved solution I will accept it. Because I know that this method is very simple and not enough for performance while getting all parts consume a lot of time(i.e for 3MB file it needs 3-5 minutes approximately).